# mysql - how to select skew row from selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
ID  - TIME - STATUS
```

Several STATUS row have '0' value. I want to select all rows that have an `ID - 2` from rows with '0' value in the STATUS column, how can I do that?

example:

```
ID - TIME - STATUS
1 - 00 - null
2 - 03 - null
3 - 02 - 0
4 - 05 - null
```

From this example I should select row with ID '1', cuz I have '0' value in the row with ID '3'

Comment: you want the results(IDs) when either of the columns(time or status) has '0' value in the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use self join on ids with difference of 2

```
select * from t
join t t1 on(t.id = t1.id - 2)
where t1.`STATUS` = '0'
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20ee7c/2)

Comment: Never knew you could adjust the join like that. Learn something new every day :).

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this with a foreach loop, then modify the key as needed:

```
$data = array(); // Pre loaded data from table.
$ids = array(); // Array of IDs - 2 with status 0.

foreach($data as $key => $row) {
    if($row['STATUS'] == 0 && isset($data[$key - 2])) {
        $ids[] = $data[$key - 2]['ID'];
    }
}
```